# Possible to send ether to another smart contract without function call?

Tags: solidity, transfer, send

I've created a contract, let's call it Contract A that mints an NFT when it receives .001 Ether.
This is the receive() function in Contract A:

```
receive() external payable {
        require(
            _vipMintCounter.current() < _vipSupply,
            "LOYALTY_MINT_SOLD_OUT"
        );
        require(msg.value >= .001 ether, "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS");
        vipMint();
    }
```

I am now creating Contract B, that when it receives .01 ether, it sends .001 ether to Contract A. This is the receive() function in Contract B:

```
receive() external payable {
        require(_wlEligible[msg.sender] > 0, "NOT_ELIGIBLE");
        require(msg.value >= .01 ether, "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS");
        uint256 wlPaidFor = msg.value / .01 ether;
        _wlEligible[msg.sender] = 0;
        _nftContractAddy.call{value: .001 ether}("");
    }
```

I've tried using send, transfer and call. All of them throw the error:

```
Error: Transaction reverted: contract call run out of gas and made the transaction revert
```

Is it possible to simply send ether to Contract A without calling a specific function?

Comment: Can you share the whole contract code?

Comment: Can you try increasing the `gasLimit` of the initial call (EOA => Contract A). You have to use call here (send and transfer will not work).

Comment: @ikijong's comment seems make sense, transfer and send will have fixed gas limit of 2300, so it's very likely that the call to contract A's receive failed due to gas limit if you used transfer or send, OR, you set quite low gas limit manually.

Answer (score 0):

The call function does not accept fractional values
You can you use something likes this

```
_nftContractAddy.call{value: uint256(1000000000000000)}("");
```

You can pass the values in Wei and 0.001ETH = 1000000000000000 wei

For better debugging change this statement to

```
(bool callSuccess,) = payable(_nftContractAddy).call{value:uint256(1000000000000000)}("");
require(callSuccess, "Call failed"); //wether the transaction went through or not
```

Comment: It's not sending fractional, .001 ether just equal to the result of (.0001 * (10** 18))

Comment: You need to convert this value, if you dont know how here is gwei converter to refer to https://eth-converter.com/